# Fallout Shelter closes after being open for a few seconds

Tags: technical-issues, ios, fallout-shelter

On my iPad, Fallout Shelter opens normally and stays open for about four seconds. Then it kicks itself out of the program back to regular screen. It doesn't stay open long enough to try to do anything

This started happening about four days ago and it worked fine before. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

First of all make sure you have connected to the Internet

Close all running apps

Check if there is an update needed

Restart the iPad, hard reset
(Hold the power & home button till the iPad restarts)

Delete the app but keep your data within game centre

(WHATEVER YOU DO DONT DELETE IT IF YOU ARENT CONNECTED TO GAME CENTRE)

Then re-download it